# Access 2010 Query - produce results for each month between two dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

The company I work for receives monthly returns from our clients. I have a table with fields including client information and the start & end dates for their returns (tbl_allocationData), and I would like to make a query that returns a list of the months that each client is due to make a return:

```
Client 1 ¦ 01/04/2018 ¦ 30/06/2018  
Client 2 ¦ 01/01/2019 ¦ 28/02/2019
```

would become

```
Client 1 ¦ April 2018  
Client 1 ¦ May 2018  
Client 1 ¦ June 2018  
Client 2 ¦ January 2019  
Client 2 ¦ February 2019
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated - apologies for the lack of attempted code but I'm on a steep learning curve with Access and this one really has me stumped so far. I have seen similar ideas where folk have used separate tables with a list of possible dates (or in my case months), but nothing that I have been able to successfully adapt to my requirements. Thanks

Comment: Create a table with all the months (12) records.  Then left join this table to each client for each year in the date range.  That way you get all months for all clients. be sure to limit the results to only those dates in the client date ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a table to serve as a month lookup, pre-populated with the start dates of every month from a given starting month until some future month (it can be years away if you like).

In the example below, table 'mths' has a single date column 'dt'.

```
select a.client, b.dt as the_month 
   from tbl_allocationData a 
      inner join mths b on b.dt between a.start_month and a.end_month
```

Result:
'client1','2018-04-01 00:00:00'
'client1','2018-05-01 00:00:00'
'client1','2018-06-01 00:00:00'

As for the date format, you can apply a date formatting function of your choice.

Comment: I have been playing around with this idea. I made a table for all the months (tbl_returnMonths) and I am trying to produce the list I am looking for with the following:

`SELECT tbl_allocationData.[School Name], tbl_returnMonths.[Return Month]  

FROM tbl_allocationData  

LEFT JOIN tbl_returnMonths ON tbl_returnMonths.[Return Month] <= tbl.allocationData.[Returns End]  

WHERE tbl_returnMonths.[Return Month]   

BETWEEN tbl_allocationData.[Returns Start] AND tbl_allocationData.[Returns End];`

This is producing the error "Syntax error in JOIN operation"... suggestions welcome!

Comment: Also apologies for commenting and deleting, I was trying to get line breaks to work but apparently it doesn't in comments!

Comment: @Matt87, change the "tbl.allocationData" to "tbl_allocationData" in "... <= tbl.allocationData.[Returns End]"

Comment: Well spotted! Although I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I made a type-o when adjusting the code, it's now working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

Have a separate table "Numbers" that just consists of one column (NumberToAdd) of sequential numbers (e.g. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.... as many rows as you need for the maximum possible range of months, I keep a very large table with positive and negative numbers as both can be useful).

Create a new query that is a Cartesian join between the Index table and your employee table.  That is, both tables are added all on their own with no links between them.

If you select ClientID and Start Date columns from the Client Table, and the NumberToAdd column from the Numbers table you will get all possible combinations - or a row for each client for each row in the Numbers table.  Now, just limit which NumberToAdd columns get returned - put a where clause on the NumberToAdd column so that you only get NumberToAdd rows that are less than the number of months different between the clients End Date and Start Date.

You can use the dateadd function in the SQL statement to get out a date representing each reporting month (use formatting in the end-user display to get in the specific date presentation form you listed in the question).

Pseudo SQL:

```
SELECT 
     tbl_Clients.*, dateadd(m, tbl_Numbers.NumberToAdd, tbl_Clients.[Start Date]) AS MonthToReport 
FROM [Actual Name of Your Clients Table] AS tbl_Clients, 
     [Actual Name of Your Numbers Table] as tbl_Numbers 
WHERE 
     tbl_Numbers.NumberToAdd >= 0 AND dateadd(m, tbl_Numbers.NumberToAdd, tbl_Clients.[Start Date]) <= tbl_Clients.[End Date]
```

You will need to play around with substituting your actual table names, and if you have time stamps in the Date fields it can get a little tricky. You may also have some adjusting needed with the <= signs depending on exactly what results you want out.